# Firemonkey Listview Dynamic Appearance Image LoadFromFile

Tags: listview, firemonkey, c++builder

I am having problem with using the FMX `TListView` with Dynamic appearance. Basically, in a custom appearance, I can allocate any images from file and it works fine. But when I use Dynamic appearance, the following give me run-time exception:

```cpp
dynamic_cast<TListItemImage*>(item->Objects->FindDrawable("Image2"))->Bitmap->LoadFromFile(StrFileName);
```

Please see my code below:

```cpp
TListViewItem* item;

while(!myQuery->Eof )
{
    item = ListView1->Items->Add();

    TListItemText * Text1 = reinterpret_cast<TListItemText*>((const_cast<TListViewItem*>(item))->Objects->FindObject("Text1"));

    if (LCaption != NULL)
    {
        Text1->Text = myQuery->FieldByName("Description1")->AsString;
    }

    UnicodeString StrFileName = L"/mnt/sdcard/test.jpg";

    dynamic_cast<TListItemImage*>(item->Objects->FindDrawable("Image2"))->Bitmap->LoadFromFile(StrFileName);

    myQuery->Next();
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `const_cast`. But more importantly, What does the runtime exception actually say? You are not checking `dynamic_cast` for failure. If you know an object's actual type ahead of time, use `static_cast` instead.  If `dynamic_cast` fails at runtime, it returns NULL, which you are not handling. Maybe `item->Objects->FindDrawable("Image2")` is returning NULL, or maybe it is returning an object that is not actually a `TListItemImage`. We don't know, since we can't see your setup. That is what you need to check for yourself.

Comment: It is not coming NULL , Im getting Acess violation at address C3EBB6B0, accessing address 00000003 error message. TListItemImage * LImage = static_cast<TListItemImage*>(item->Objects->FindObject("Image2"));
    if(LImage!=NULL)
    {
     LImage->Bitmap->LoadFromFile(L"/mnt/sdcard/test.jpg");
    }    
       }

Comment: I have managed with only to creating a TImage *myImage object and did LoadFromFile and LImage->Bitmap = myImage->Bitmap , if it does take the image fom TImage why it is not getting directly with LoadFromFile as I have not problem in Custom Apprance.

Comment: "*Acess violation at address C3EBB6B0, accessing address 00000003*" - when an AV happens near address 0, it means a NULL pointer is being accessed. In this case, accessing a data member at byte offset 3 within a class, when the pointer to the class instance is NULL. You need to use the debugger to find that NULL pointer. Make sure `item` and `item->Objects` are not NULL, that `FindObject("Image2")` does not return NULL, that `LImage->Bitmap` is not NULL. If all of that is OK, and the AV is coming from inside `LoadFromFile()`, then it is likely an implementation bug that should be reported.

Comment: Following code working perfectly fine. It seems there is a bug if we try to loadthe picture directly. By the way it doesnt fall into the null .. UnicodeString StrFileName = L"/mnt/sdcard/test.jpg";

    TListItemImage * LImage = static_cast<TListItemImage*>(item->Objects->FindObject("Image2"));

    TImage *myImage = new TImage(NULL);
    myImage->Bitmap->LoadFromFile(StrFileName);
    if(LImage!=NULL)
    {
     LImage->Bitmap = myImage->Bitmap;
    }

       delete myImage;

Comment: There should be no difference whatsoever between `LImage->Bitmap.LoadFromFile(...);` vs `myImage->Bitmap->LoadFromFile(...); LImage->Bitmap = myImage->Bitmap;` I would consider this a bug that needs to be [reported to Embarcadero](https://quality.embarcadero.com).

Comment: Thanks a lot to confirm that.. I will report it as bug.